# Order Wordpress custom posts by custom feilds

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to order custom posts by custom fields. this is my code.

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'pql_Servay',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 2, 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'question_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

This code works for displaying all posts on a single page. But I want to display one post per page.

I am using this code to get next post page link.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_link(); ?>">Next Post</a>
```

But When I click this link next page also shows the first post. In short next post is displaying the same post on the first page.

I am creating a shortcode to display these posts.

Here is complete shortcode

```
<?php 

add_shortcode( 'PreQualifyingLeads', 'PreQualifyingLeads_shortcode');

function PreQualifyingLeads_shortcode(){

    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'pql_Servay',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 2, 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key'  => 'question_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    ?>
    <div class="pql-wrapper">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <h2>This is page  Title </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="Question-Wrapper">
            <?php 
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                if($loop->have_posts()){

                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                     $loop->the_post(); 
                    echo  the_title( ).'<br>';
                    }
                }

                wp_reset_postdata(  );             
            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_link()?>">Next Post</a>


        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Is you get_next_posts_page_link button inside the WP_Query? And in which template are you placing the above code?

Comment: I tried using it both ways inside and also outside the loop. But it doesn't work.
I am trying to make a shortcode to show Custom Post type. One Post on one page.

Comment: Show your shortcode code please

Comment: @HowardE added the shortcode to question Please check.

Comment: You accepted an answer. Is it working?  Or do you have a problem still?  It doesn't look like your shortcode will work.

Comment: @HowardE This shortcode does not work for the homepage but It works fine on other pages. I have no idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add paged parameter in your query like following:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
'paged' => $paged
```

Your wp query should look like the following:

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'pql_Servay',
    'paged' => $paged
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'question_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: this code does not work for front page but working on other pages. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be its run

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type'      => 'pql_Servay',
    'paged'          => $paged
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby'        =>   array(
      'question_order'=>'ASC
     )
 );
```